# Cakephp 1.3 cookie httponly not working

Tags: php, cakephp, cookies, session-cookies, cakephp-1.3

I want to set cookie onlyHttp in cakePHP 1.3 for this i have search many thing and apply many solutions but they are not working. Same solution is working for CakePHP 2.0 and higher version, can any one suggest me solution for set cookie Onlyhttp in CakePHP 1.3.

Answer (score 1):

CakePHP 1.3 uses [__write()](http://api.cakephp.org/1.3/source-class-CookieComponent.html#187-231) function to set cookie. Which sets cookie useing:

```
setcookie(
   $this->name . $name, 
   $this->__encrypt($value), 
   $this->__expires, 
   $this->path, 
   $this->domain, 
   $this->secure
);
```

As You can see httpOnly parameter is never passed. You can either:

- use setcookie function directly in Your app
- extend CookieComponent to support httpOnly flag
- Hack CakePHP core CookieComponent files to add support for httpOnly parameter (not recomended bus CakePHP 1.3 is no longer supported, so...)

Answer (score 0):

I you're using PHP 5.2 or above you can set httpOnly cookie with simple **setcookie** - in PHP 5.2 httponly flag was introduced

```
bool setcookie ( string $name [, string $value = "" [, int $expire = 0 [, string $path = "" [, string $domain = "" [, bool $secure = false [, bool $httponly = false ]]]]]] )
```

CakePHP added httpOnly feature to its Cookie component in CakePHP 2.0